# Как выполнить событие только после полной загрузки картинок?

Tags: jquery, ajax, изображения

Подгружаю картинки на страницу.

Как выполнить событие только после полной загрузки картинок?

Нужно что-то наподобие `$(window).load(function()`.

Answer (score 1):

А чем load к картинке не устроил?

Вот велосипедик http://noteskeeper.ru/35/